# Wie sagt man für eine "left-over" Frau auf Deutsch?

Tags: meaning

Hallo meine Experten,

wie nennt man eine "left-over"-Frau auf Deutsch? Gibt es abwertende oder neutrale Wörter für die Frauen, die nicht verheiratet sind? (1. weil keiner sie will oder auch 2. weil sie keinen will).
Gibt es auch solches Wort für einen "left-over"-Mann?

Comment: Menschen als left-over zu bezeichnen, finde ich sehr bedenklich. Wer nicht verheiratet ist, ist ledig oder schlicht unverheiratet.

Comment: @Olofant: Du hast zwar recht, aber hier geht es nicht um die moralisch/ethische Bewertung, sondern darum, ob es in einer Sprache dafür einen speziellen Ausdruck gibt. Auch abwertende und beleidigende Begriffe sind Bestandteile aller lebenden Sprachen, und man sollte sie wenigstens im passiven Wortschatz parat haben, um sie zu verstehen.

Comment: @Olafant "left-over" ist durchaus ein gängiger Begriff, z.B. in China (*Sheng-nu*, *guang gun*). Dann sollte es auch eine Übersetzung dafür geben - egal ob einem der Begriff gefällt oder nicht.

Comment: @Olafant: Ich habe eine Tante, die war nie verheiratet und ist jetzt knapp 70 und die bezeichnen sich selbst als "übriggebliebene alte Schachtel". Aber meine Tante lacht viel und ich hab den Eindruck, dass sie ganz zufrieden mit ihrem Leben ist.  Den Begriff "left-over" gibt's also auch im Deutschen.

Comment: Vielen Dank für eure super Erklärung 

Answer (score 10):

Es gibt Begriffe wie [alte Jungfer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jungfer) oder [Hagestolz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagestolz). Die sind allerdings nicht nur veraltet (nicht jeder Muttersprachler wird sie noch kennen), sondern auch mindestens abwertend, wenn nicht beleidigend. Ich rate also davon ab, sie zu verwenden. Insgesamt ist es, wie schon Olafant in seinem Kommentar angesprochen hat, sehr bedenklich, Menschen als "left-over" zu bezeichnen. Wenn man das Thema überhaupt ansprechen will, sollte man neutrale Begriffe wie "ledig" oder "unverheiratet" verwenden.

Comment: Es geht bei Sprache nicht immer darum, Begriffe aktiv zu verwenden, sondern manchmal auch darum, Begriffe, die andere benutzen, zu verstehen und richtig einzuordnen. Als ich in der Schule Englisch gelernt habe, habe ich immer sehr bedauert, dass wir keine Schimpfwörter gelernt haben. Das ist Teil jeder lebendigen Sprache, und wenn man bereits alt genug ist, um ganz legal viele Dinge zu tun, die man als Kind oder Jugendlicher noch nicht durfte, dann sollten einem auch diese Teile einer Sprache nicht vorenthalten werden.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Die Begriffe werden in der Antwort explizit genannt, sogar verlinkt, und sinnvoll mit nützlichem Wissen dazu eingeordnet. Das finde ich genau richtig so.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast In der Antwort steht **nicht** "es gibt Begriffe, ich sag' sie dir aber nicht", sondern es ist alles schön erklärt und es wird auch darauf hingewiesen, dass diese Begriffe traditionell eher abwertend verwendet werden. Von "vorenthalten" kann also keine Rede sein. Alles richtig gemacht.

Comment: Ich empfehle, den Teil dieser Antwort von "Ich rate ..." bis "... ansprechen will" zu löschen und die letzte Satzhälfte passend umzuformulieren. Nachdem bereits völlig korrekt gesagt wurde, dass die Begriffe "abwertend" bis "beleidigend" sind, wird hier keine zusätzliche Information vermittelt. Generelle Ratschläge, was man tun oder nicht tun sollte, halte ich für ziemlich daneben, so lange man den Kontext überhaupt nicht kennt. Möchte der OP beispielsweise seine in der beschriebenen Situation befindliche Nachbarin ansprechen, so sollte er *nicht* den Begriff "alte Jungfer" verwenden, ...

Comment: ... möchte er hingegen in einer Erzählung die Worte eines unliebsamen Zeitgenossen, der sich über das Unverheiratetsein einer anderen Person lustig macht, in wörtlicher Rede wiedergeben, so sollte er *sehr wohl* den Begriff "alte Jungfer" verwenden.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ich denke, das mit dem Zitat ist so selbstverständlich und offensichtlich, dass es nicht extra erwähnt werden muss.

Comment: @tofro: Dass man einen Begriff, der als "abwertend" oder "beleidigend" eingestuft wurde, nicht zum Ausdruck der eigenen Meinung über eine reale Person verwenden sollte (wenn einem daran gelegen ist, respektvoll zu bleiben), ist aber auch so selbstverständlich und offensichtlich, dass es nicht extra erwähnt werden muss.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Dann verstehe ich nicht, warum du den Vorschlag machst, einer Ausage, die du für überflüssig und selbstverständlich hältst, eine zweite solche hinzuzufügen?

Comment: @tofro: Ich habe nicht vorgeschlagen, etwas hinzuzufügen, sondern etwas zu entfernen.

Answer (score 6):

*Überzeugter Junggeselle* oder die entsprechende weibliche Form ([DWDS: Junggesellin](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Junggesellin); zwar kein besonders schönes Wort, aber immerhin durch *Junggesellinnenabschied* etabliert) schreibt die Entscheidung zwar der betroffenen Person selbst zu, verletzt damit aber zumindest niemanden.

Answer (score 3):

Ich würde die wörtliche Übersetzung vorschlagen: Wer in einem gewissen Alter noch nicht „fest vergeben“ ist, während alle Freunde und Bekannten schon Kinderwagen aussuchen, den kann schon mal das Gefühl beschleichen, **übriggeblieben** zu sein (vom Verb *übrig bleiben* = to be left over).

Kurze Google-Abfrage bestätigt, daß der Begriff recht gängig ist, wenn auch oft in tatsächlichen oder doch zumindest gefühlten Anführungszeichen:

- „Internet-Partnersuche verlieh durch die von ihr abgelösten Zeitungsannoncen den Geschmack, eine „Übriggebliebene“ oder ein wahrer Sonderling zu sein“ ([Ewig single und jetzt doch in Beziehung - ein Erfolgsbericht](https://community.parship.de/forum/thema/ewig-single-und-jetzt-doch-in-beziehung-ein-erfolgsbericht.14241/))
- [Wir Übriggebliebenen haben Pech – wir werden alleine sterben](https://www.beziehungsweise-magazin.de/paare/liebesgeschichten/wir-uebriggebliebenen-haben-pech-wir-werden-alleine-sterben/)
- Ein weiteres Gefühl, von dem man heimgesucht werden kann, ist das ziemlich schwierige des Übriggebliebenseins. Es macht einen Unterschied, in welchem Jahrzehnt des Lebens man Single ist. ([Die Sache mit dem Single-Sein](https://einguterplan.de/single-sein/))

Vorsicht: Gerade wenn man andere so bezeichnet, kann das schnell ziemlich abwertend wirken (ist aber im Englischen sicher auch nicht anders).

Answer (score -3):

Ein Begriff, für den es allerdings kein maskulines Pendant gibt, wäre *Mauerblümchen*, das es auch auf Englisch ("wallflower", mit gleicher Bedeutung) gibt.

Das Wort hat milde abwertende Konnotation (weniger stark als etwa "alte Jungfer", aber das ist wohl auch Ansichtssache).

Comment: Ein Mauerblümchen ist aber was anderes - Das ist ein unscheinbares, schüchternes Mädchen, das keinen Kontakt findet.

Comment: @tofro: ja, das stimmt. Wenn Du mir sagst, was genau die intendierte Übersetzung von "left-over" gewesen wäre, dann kann ich Dir sagen, ob emin Vorschlag adäquat wäre oder nicht. Tatsache ist jedenfalls, daß "keinen Kontakt finden" und "keinen Mann haben" schon irgendwie zusammenhängen, findest Du nicht?

Comment: Das "Mauerblümchen" ist typischerweise ein schüchternes junges Mädchen, das neben dem Tanzboden "auf der Mauer sitzt", während alle anderen Mädchen Kontakt finden und dort mit Jungs tanzen. Das mag 40 Jahre vor der "alten Jungfer" sein, aber nicht notwendigerweise - Vielleicht findet sich ja doch noch ein Blumenliebhaber. Genausogut könntest du argumentieren, dass *Säugling* und *Opa* "schon irgendwie zusammenhängt".

Comment: @tofro: fassen wir also zusammen: Du bist der Meinung, daß "alte Jungfer" die richtige Übersetzung für "'left-over' Frau" ist, und deshalb ist meine Vermutung, daß unter Umständen auch was anderes gemeint sein könnte, falsch. Findest Du nicht, daß Du im Kreis argumentierst? Daß "Mauerblümchen" "40 Jahre vor der 'alten Jungfer' [ist]" ist erstens nur eine Behauptung (wer sagt, daß es keine alten Mauerblümchen gibt?) und setzt zweitens voraus, daß "alte Jungfer" überhaupt die richtige Übersetzung ist, was Du ja dadurch erst zu belegen suchst - hysteron proteron.

Comment: "alte Jungfer" ist sicher nicht die richtige Übersetzung für die chinesischen *Sheng-nu* (wonach, denke ich, gefragt ist.). Da unsere Gesellschaft dieses soziale Phänomen von unverheirateten Frauen im mittleren Alter, die sich "dem Heiratsmarkt entziehen", der von einem Männerüberschuss geplagt ist, überhaupt nicht kennt, sind Übersetzungen schwierig - weshalb ich mich einer eigenen Antwort bisher auch komplett enthalten habe. Was ich argumentiere ist, dass *Mauerblümchen* nun eben leider *überhaupt nicht* passt, und zwar wegen der implizierten Beweggründe: Ein Mauerblümchen ......

Comment: ..... ist einsam und *möchte* (unterstellt) einen Partner, ist aber zu schüchtern oder zu sozial inkompatibel, (oder zu unatttraktiv) um einen kennenzulernen. Der Begriff "leftover woman"  unterstellt aber eine gewisse Böswilligkeit, mit der sich die Frau dem Heiratsmarkt aktiv entzieht - diese unterstellte Böswilligkeit ist in der "alten Jungfer" möglicherweise minimal vorhanden, im "Mauerblümchen" gar nicht. *Sheng-nu* unterstellt ebenfalls "aktives Entziehen" statt, wie beim Mauerblümchen "passives Nicht-gefunden-werden".  Nein, "alte Jungfer" passt nicht. "Mauerblümchen aber **gar nicht**.

Comment: @tofro: ok, Deine Argumentation leuchtet mir ein, ABER: diesen Hintergrund und die daraus folgenden Konnotationen hättest Du auch gleich in einem Kommentar ansprechen können und das hätte mir (und wahrscheinlich auch anderen) vermutlich geholfen, bessere Antworten zu formulieren. Ich jedenfalls spreche kein Wort chinesisch und war mir dieses Zusammenhangs in keiner Weise bewußt. Vielleicht hätte es auch den OP angeregt, ein paar erklärende Worte zu verlieren und zu verdeutlichen, was *er* eigentlich meint. Zumindest aus der Formulierung "left-over Frau" ging das nämlich in keiner Weise hervor.

Comment: @tofro: ich sehe grade, daß Du das getan hast, mir aber der Kommentar entgangen war. Na gut, mea culpa.